# Is there a way to programmatically unregister a device for push notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

Just wondering if this is actually possible. So I can stop all notifications kind of like how notification center has the option to stop all notification.

I don't believe this is possible, but wondering what you might think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications) should be used, in Objective-C.

`UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` in Swift.

Comment: "You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the application drops support for remote notifications."

Comment: I am confused why you must only call this in rare circumstances?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[UIApplication unregisterForRemoteNotifications]` since the question was tagged 'ios'? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Pyraego.com, I learned the hard way not to use `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`. Calling it would at times put the app in a state where calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` would no longer work.

Answer (score 5):

The push notifications are sent from your server... so you should implement such a method yourself and remove or disable the device in the database on your server where you store the active devices.

If you only disable them locally on your device your server will still send messages until you get notification from the feedback service.. which you should check...

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 4 and above**

```
UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
```

You can call this method after a user logout that you will be sure that the next user to connect will have a unique device token.